# Combining / merging object members in a list

Tags: java, java-11

I got a list of objects from class A in a list.
Some of these objects are equal in id and name but not in list <B> , and list b is ALWAYS different.

I need to merge these so that my list is only made out of object a's with same name and id exists and all the b from same group are collected
I can make use of jdk 8 plus utils so streams are ok to use here.. Although I think reflection here is more usable?

PS: I can not change content of a of b class as they are generated classes and no access / expansion possibility

```
    @Test
    public void test() {
        List.of(new A(1, "a1", List.of(new B(1, "1b"))),
                new A(1, "a1", List.of(new B(2, "2b"))),
                new A(2, "a2", List.of(new B(3, "3b"))));
//expected
        List.of(new A(1, "a1", List.of(new B(1, "1b"), new B(2, "2b"))),
                new A(2, "a2", List.of(new B(3, "3b"))));


    }


    class A {
        public A(int id, String name, List<B> listB) {
            this.id = id;
            this.name = name;
            this.listB = listB;
        }
        int id;
        String name;
        List<B> listB;
    }

    class B {
        public B(int id, String name) {
            this.id = id;
            this.name = name;
        }
        int id;
        String name;
    }
```

Comment: They share a common super class or something? What's the input format?

Comment: nop .. A is huge class and B too xD and no connection, here are the property  names indeed misleading

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use

```java
record Key(int id, String name) {};

List<A> result = input.stream().collect(
    Collectors.groupingBy(a -> new Key(a.getId(), a.getName()),
        LinkedHashMap::new,
        Collectors.flatMapping(a -> a.getListB().stream(), Collectors.toList())))
    .entrySet().stream()
    .map(e -> new A(e.getKey().id(), e.getKey().name(), e.getValue()))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());

if(!result.equals(expected)) {
    throw new AssertionError("expected " + expected + " but got " + result);
}
```

This constructs new lists with new `A` objects, which is suitable for immutable objects. Your use of `List.of(…)` suggests a preference towards immutable objects. If you have mutable objects and want to perform the operation in-place, you could do

```java
List<A> result = new ArrayList<>(input); // only needed if input is an immutable list

record Key(int id, String name) {};
HashMap<Key,A> previous = new HashMap<>();

result.removeIf(a -> previous.merge(new Key(a.getId(), a.getName()), a, (old, newA) -> {
        var l = old.getListB();
        if(l.getClass() != ArrayList.class) old.setListB(l = new ArrayList<>(l));
        l.addAll(newA.getListB());
        return old;
    }) != a);

if(!result.equals(expected)) {
    throw new AssertionError("expected " + expected + " but got " + result);
}
```

This removes the duplicates from the list and adds their `B`s to the previously encountered original. It does the minimum of changes required to get the intended list, e.g. if there are no duplicates, it does nothing.

If `A` objects with the same id always have the same name, in other words, there is no need for a key object checking both, you could simplify this approach to

```java
List<A> result = new ArrayList<>(input); // only needed if input is an immutable list

HashMap<Integer,A> previous = new HashMap<>();

result.removeIf(a -> previous.merge(a.getId(), a, (old, newA) -> {
        var l = old.getListB();
        if(l.getClass() != ArrayList.class) old.setListB(l = new ArrayList<>(l));
        l.addAll(newA.getListB());
        return old;
    }) != a);

if(!result.equals(expected)) {
    throw new AssertionError("expected " + expected + " but got " + result);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need preserve an instance for each `id` you can write (I assume objects have getters and setters)

```
System.out.println(xs.stream()
        .collect(groupingBy(A::getId, toList()))
        .values().stream()
        .peek(g -> g.get(0).setListB(
                g.stream()
                        .flatMap(h -> h.getListB().stream())
                        .collect(groupingBy(B::getId, toList()))
                        .values().stream()
                        .map(i -> i.get(0))
                        .collect(toList())))
        .map(g -> g.get(0))
        .collect(toList()));
```

your input case with output

```
[A(id=1, name=a1, listB=[B(id=1, name=b1), B(id=2, name=b2)]), A(id=2, name=a2, listB=[B(id=3, name=b3)])]
```

if you can create new instances then you can renormalize the lists

```
System.out.println(xs.stream()
        .flatMap(a -> a.getListB().stream().map(b -> List.<Object>of(a.id, a.name, b.id, b.name)))
        .distinct()
        .collect(groupingBy(o -> o.get(0), toList()))
        .values()
        .stream()
        .map(zs -> new A((int) zs.get(0).get(0), (String) zs.get(0).get(1),
                zs.stream().map(z -> new B((int) z.get(2), (String) z.get(3))).collect(toList())))
        .collect(toList()));
```

(you can change the ugly `.get(0).get(0)` using some intermediate class called `DenormalizedRow` or so)

Comment: only problem here i do not know which part of B is filled in, i just know they are always different:-S but they can be even null ...you will not have 2 nulls for same A though!

Comment: @UnnameDSoS filter as required every stream

Comment: would it be possible to create a collector from this ? or would it not be possible since you need previous item?

Comment: @UnnameDSoS I do not understand your question (you can create a collector but, why?)